# ManyToMany EclipseLink Insert

Tags: mysql, insert, eclipselink

i think the real problem is that i can't get an id of a recently persisted entity(i don't know how). I'm using eclipseLink 2.1 and mysql 5.1.7 so i leave my entity classes

the join table of the many to many , is ProductosVentas; sorry for spanish namings

please help me

here is my script

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    EntityManager em = EclipseLinkUtil.getEntityManagerFactory();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    try {
        Query query = em
            .createQuery("from Productos p where p.nombre like 'Lavado de motor' ");
        Productos selledItem = (Productos) query.getSingleResult();
        query = em.createNativeQuery("select curdate() ");
        java.sql.Date sellingDate = (Date) query.getSingleResult();
        Ventas v1 = new Ventas();
        v1.setCondicionventaIdcondicionventa(new Condicionventa(1));
        v1.setFecha(sellingDate);
        List<Productosventas> selledItemTableList = new ArrayList<>();
        v1.setProductosventasCollection(selledItemTableList);
        Productosventas p = new Productosventas();
        p.setVentas(v1);
        p.setCantidad(1);
        p.setProductos(selledItem);
        selledItemTableList.add(p);
        em.persist(v1);
        em.persist(p);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

error

> ```java
> Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
> ```
>
> Column 'ventas_idventa' cannot be null
>       Error Code: 1048
>       Call: INSERT INTO productosventas (cantidad, ventas_idventa, productos_idProductos, PriceModifiers_idPriceModifier) VALUES (?, ?,
>   ?, ?)
>         bind => [4 parameters bound]

those are my entities

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "productos")
@XmlRootElement
public class Productos implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "productos")
    private Collection<Productosventas> productosventasCollection;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idProductos")
    private Integer idProductos;
    // [properties]
    @JoinColumn(name = "PriceModifiers_idPriceModifier",
            referencedColumnName = "idPriceModifier")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Pricemodifiers priceModifiersidPriceModifier;
    @JoinColumn(name = "AreaServicio_idAreaServicio",
            referencedColumnName = "idAreaServicio")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Areaservicio areaServicioidAreaServicio;
    @JoinColumn(name = "formaventa_idFormaVenta",
            referencedColumnName = "idFormaVenta")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Formaventa formaventaidFormaVenta;

    // geters and setters
    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Productosventas> getProductosventasCollection() {
        return productosventasCollection;
    }

    public void setProductosventasCollection(
            Collection<Productosventas> productosventasCollection) {
        this.productosventasCollection = productosventasCollection;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ventas")
@XmlRootElement
public class Ventas implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "ventas")
    private Collection<Productosventas> productosventasCollection;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idventa")
    private Integer idventa;
    @Column(name = "fecha")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date fecha;
    @JoinColumn(name = "condicionventa_idcondicionventa",
            referencedColumnName = "idcondicionventa")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Condicionventa condicionventaIdcondicionventa;
    @JoinColumn(name = "climas_idclimas", referencedColumnName = "idclimas")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Climas climasIdclimas;
    @JoinColumn(name = "cliente_idcliente", referencedColumnName = "idcliente")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Cliente clienteIdcliente;
    @JoinColumn(name = "cars_numberplate", referencedColumnName = "numberplate")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Cars carsNumberplate;

    // getters and setters
    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Productosventas> getProductosventasCollection() {
        return productosventasCollection;
    }

    public void setProductosventasCollection(
            Collection<Productosventas> productosventasCollection) {
        this.productosventasCollection = productosventasCollection;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "productosventas")
@XmlRootElement
public class Productosventas implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected ProductosventasPK productosventasPK;
    @Column(name = "cantidad")
    private Integer cantidad;
    @JoinColumn(name = "PriceModifiers_idPriceModifier",
            referencedColumnName = "idPriceModifier")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Pricemodifiers priceModifiersidPriceModifier;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ventas_idventa", referencedColumnName = "idventa",
            insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Ventas ventas;
    @JoinColumn(name = "productos_idProductos",
            referencedColumnName = "idProductos", insertable = false,
            updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Productos productos;

    public Productosventas() {}

    public Productosventas(ProductosventasPK productosventasPK) {
        this.productosventasPK = productosventasPK;
    }

    public Productosventas(int ventasIdventa, int productosidProductos) {
        this.productosventasPK = new ProductosventasPK(ventasIdventa,
            productosidProductos);
    }

    public ProductosventasPK getProductosventasPK() {
        return productosventasPK;
    }

    public void setProductosventasPK(ProductosventasPK productosventasPK) {
        this.productosventasPK = productosventasPK;
    }

    // geters and setters
}

@Embeddable
public class ProductosventasPK implements Serializable {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ventas_idventa")
    private int ventasIdventa;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "productos_idProductos")
    private int productosidProductos;

    public ProductosventasPK() {}

    public ProductosventasPK(int ventasIdventa, int productosidProductos) {
        this.ventasIdventa = ventasIdventa;
        this.productosidProductos = productosidProductos;
    }

    // geters and setters

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (int) ventasIdventa;
        hash += (int) productosidProductos;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are
        // not set
        if (!(object instanceof ProductosventasPK)) {
            return false;
        }
        ProductosventasPK other = (ProductosventasPK) object;
        if (this.ventasIdventa != other.ventasIdventa) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.productosidProductos != other.productosidProductos) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "tiendita.entities.ProductosventasPK[ ventasIdventa="
            + ventasIdventa + ", productosidProductos=" + productosidProductos
            + " ]";
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I tried to flush first (thanks to chris) but it looks ugly and long and unecesary ... this seems to be the fancy way but its written with hibernate too bad i'm using eclipselink. i hope this code can be written the same way.

```java
session.beginTransaction();

Stock stock = new Stock();
stock.setStockCode("7052");
stock.setStockName("PADINI");

Category category1 = new Category("CONSUMER", "CONSUMER COMPANY");
//new category, need save to get the id first
session.save(category1);

StockCategory stockCategory = new StockCategory();
stockCategory.setStock(stock);
stockCategory.setCategory(category1);
stockCategory.setCreatedDate(new Date()); //extra column
stockCategory.setCreatedBy("system"); //extra column

stock.getStockCategories().add(stockCategory);

session.save(stock);

session.getTransaction().commit();
```

this seems very rudimentary

```java
EntityManager em = EclipseLinkUtil.getEntityManagerFactory();

em.getTransaction().begin();
try {

    Query query = em.createQuery("from Productos p where p.nombre like 'Lavado de motor' ");
    Productos selledItem = (Productos) query.getSingleResult();

    query = em.createNativeQuery("select curdate() ");
    java.sql.Date sellingDate = (Date) query.getSingleResult();

    Ventas v1 = new Ventas();
    v1.setCondicionventaIdcondicionventa(new Condicionventa(1));
    v1.setFecha(sellingDate);

    List<Productosventas> selledItemTableList = new ArrayList<>();
    v1.setProductosventasCollection(selledItemTableList);
    em.persist(v1);
    em.flush();

    Productosventas p = new Productosventas();
    p.setProductosventasPK(new ProductosventasPK(v1.getIdventa(), selledItem.getIdProductos()));
    p.setCantidad(1);
    p.setProductos(selledItem);
    selledItemTableList.add(p);

    p = new Productosventas();
    p.setProductosventasPK(new ProductosventasPK(v1.getIdventa(), selledItem.getIdProductos()));
    p.setCantidad(2);
    selledItemTableList.add(p);
    selledItem.setProductosventasCollection(selledItemTableList);

    em.persist(selledItem);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    em.getTransaction().rollback();
} finally {
    em.close();
}
```

what i hate most is this

```java
    em.persist(v1);
    em.flush();
    Productosventas p = new Productosventas();
    p.setProductosventasPK(new ProductosventasPK(v1.getIdventa(), selledItem.getIdProductos()));
    p.setCantidad(1);
    p.setProductos(selledItem);
```

**second edit**

```java
public class ProductosventasPK implements Serializable {

     private int ventas;

    private int productos;

    public ProductosventasPK() {
    }

    public ProductosventasPK(int ventasIdventa, int productosidProductos) {
        this.ventas = ventasIdventa;
        this.productos = productosidProductos;
    }
    // geters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "tiendita.entities.ProductosventasPK[ ventasIdventa=" + ventas
            + ", productosidProductos=" + productos + " ]";
    }

}

@Entity
@IdClass(ProductosventasPK.class)
@Table(name = "productosventas", catalog = "tiendita", schema = "")
public class Productosventas implements Serializable {
@JoinColumn(name = "productos_idProductos", referencedColumnName = "idProductos",
        insertable = true, updatable = true)
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private Productos productos;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ventas_idventa", referencedColumnName = "idventa",
        insertable = true, updatable = true)
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Ventas ventas;

    ProductosventasPK productosventasPK;
//important parts

}
```

the rest remains exactly the same

**Final Edit**

> [EL Warning]: 2013-09-25 17:14:14.291--ServerSession(1770214826)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'PRODUCTOSVENTASPK' in 'field list'
>   Error Code: 1054
>   Call: SELECT cantidad, PRODUCTOSVENTASPK, PriceModifiers_idPriceModifier, productos_idProductos, ventas_idventa FROM tiendita.productosventas WHERE (productos_idProductos = ?)
>       bind => [1 parameter bound]
>   Query: ReadAllQuery(name="productosventasList" referenceClass=Productosventas sql="SELECT cantidad, PRODUCTOSVENTASPK, PriceModifiers_idPriceModifier, productos_idProductos, ventas_idventa FROM tiendita.productosventas WHERE (productos_idProductos = ?)")
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)

```java
public class Productosventas implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Column(name = "cantidad")
    private Integer cantidad;
    @JoinColumn(name = "PriceModifiers_idPriceModifier", referencedColumnName = "idPriceModifier")
    @ManyToOne
    private Pricemodifiers priceModifiersidPriceModifier;
    @JoinColumn(name = "productos_idProductos", referencedColumnName = "idProductos", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private Productos productos;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ventas_idventa", referencedColumnName = "idventa", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Ventas ventas;
    @Transient//transistent worked like a charm
    ProductosventasPK productosventasPK;
...rest of the class }
```

Now i insert as i wish

```java
public static void prueba2() {
    EntityManager em = EclipseLinkUtil.getEntityManagerFactory();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    try {
        Query query = em.createQuery("from Productos p where p.nombre like 'Lavado de motor' ");
        Productos selledItem = (Productos) query.getSingleResult();
        query = em.createQuery("from Productos p where p.nombre like 'Lavado de ventana' ");
        Productos selledItem2 = (Productos) query.getSingleResult();

    // query = em.createNativeQuery("select curdate() ");
    //java.sql.Date sellingDate = (Date) query.getSingleResult();
        java.util.Date sellingDate = new java.util.Date();

        Ventas v1 = new Ventas();
        v1.setCondicionventaIdcondicionventa(new Condicionventa(1));
        v1.setFecha(sellingDate);

        List<Productosventas> selledItemTableList = new ArrayList<>();
        Productosventas pdv = new Productosventas();
        Productosventas pdv2 = new Productosventas();
        em.persist(v1);

        pdv.setCantidad(2);
        pdv.setProductos(selledItem);
        pdv.setVentas(v1);
        pdv2.setCantidad(2);
        pdv2.setProductos(selledItem2);
        pdv2.setVentas(v1);

        selledItem.getProductosventasList().add(pdv);
        selledItem.getProductosventasList().add(pdv2);

        v1.setProductosventasList(selledItemTableList);


        em.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what the solution was. Please edit your post adding info after each edit what describing what you changed and what did not work after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the ID values to use in Productosventas you will need to persist the referenced entities and then call flush to have the provider issue SQL inserts for them.  Only then can the IDs be set from the database when using the identity strategy, while table sequencing generally allows preallocation and so they can be available on the persist call.  After that, you can get them from the entities and set them within Productosventas' embeddedid.

An alternative if you can use JPA 2.0 features is to use derived id.  For Productosventas, all you need to do is mark priceModifiersidPriceModifier with @MapsId("productosidProductos") and The provider will use the relationship to set the embeddedid field for you when it assigns the IDs.  Do the same for the other relationship, and you can persist all 3 entities at the same time and ID values will be set after the flush or comit for all 3.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/2.0/DerivedIdentifiers
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/JPA_2.0/mappedbyid

Comment: hello chris i have problems with @MapsId annotation(once i run i get Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@40f23491) i would like to accomplish something like this http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/ 4. Run it – Case 1 For a new category and a new stock. i think you say i can do something similar. look at the diagram and stock is productos, category is ventas and stock_category is productosventas

Comment: Your error does not seem related to the @MapsId annotation itself.  Do you have the correct JPA 2.0 persistence.jar on the classpath?  JPA does not allow the pk to have relationships, and I don't see the point in putting a relationship in an embeddableid; it means you will have to look up the referenced entities to build a pk each time you want to do a simple find operation - the example then even abstracts the embeddedid so that the entity accesses the relationship as if it owns it.  Isn't it better to just have the relation in the entity itself and mark it as the ID?

Comment: yes i use eclipselink 2.1 no problem with that & netbeans wizard that means i cannot control the creation of entities unless i modify them , i agree with you(embeddableid) why to add and extra class i just want to. would you mind showing me the way to  "Isn't it better to just have the relation in the entity itself and mark it as the ID?" i'm very new to jpa and in top of that i encounter more difficult than other newbies really i'm lost just look at my post edit. Regards

Comment: The first link I posted shows a simple composite pk using a relationship as part of the pk.  If you followed that example, all you needed to change was to remove the productosventasPK attribute, make ProductosventasPK a PKClass for the entity, and change ProductosventasPK to rename attributes ventasIdventa and productosidProductos to ventas and productos respectively.  You also need to make the ventas and productos mappings within Productosventas insertable/updatable=true

Comment: sorry for my brutality but just remember we are close to finish =) i tried everything but i got this Exception [EclipseLink-46] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException please see the second edit
Exception Description: There should be one non-read-only mapping defined for the primary key field [tiendita.productosventas.ventas_idventa].
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(tiendita.entities.Productosventas --> [DatabaseTable(tiendita.productosventas)])

Runtime Exceptions:

Comment: The code you've shown wont result in the error, so check something else isn't on the classpath, such as an old attempt.

Comment: man you are awesome ! i screw it up by adding @id to roductosventasPK productosventasPK in productosventas if i erase this mapping i get an error just see the final edit